# How to fix the javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have a website with an automatic updating footer, where you can find the date. But the footer gives the complete wrong date. This is the code behind it:

```
$(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var mm = now.getMonth() + 1;
    $("#footer").html(`&copy; NekoLuka ${now.getFullYear()}/${mm}/${now.getDay()}`);
}
```

Today is 2018/10/24, But the footer gives 2018/10/3.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Your first stop should be [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), which tells you that `getDay` returns the **day of the week**. You're looking for [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), which returns the day of the month.

Comment: now.getDay() // returns day of week;, use now.getDate();

Comment: https://www.copyrightlaws.com/copyright-notice-year/ — Your copyright notice should display the date of first publication, not today's date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 5):

Look at [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You are using `getDay`:

> Returns the **day of the week** (0-6) for the specified date according to local time.

You should be using `getDate`:

> Returns the day of the month (1-31) for the specified date according to local time.

Answer (score 3):

`now.getDay()` gets the date of the week, you need `now.getDate()` to get the current day

Answer (score 1):

The date is coming wrong because you are using `getDay` to get current date instead of `getDate`

replace `now.getDay()` with `now.getDate()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I used the `getDay()` instead of the `getDate()`. When I used the `getDate()`, the script worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `now.getDate()` instead of `now.getDay()`